# nginx proxy_pass requests to fqdn without converting to IP

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I am trying to proxy_pass requests using nginx to a public fqdn.
The server has LB configured only to respond to requests when accessed using fqdn and get an ssl hand shake error when accessed using IP.

My issue is that the nginx is implicitly converting the fqdn to set of IPs and trying them one by one and failing.
Is there a way have nginx proxy_pass without converting the fqdn to IP and route the request to upstream at fqdn?

```
        location /public/api {
            proxy_pass https://public.server.com/api;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

```
2022/04/24 23:10:20 [error] 912419#912419: *5 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: xxxxxxxx, server: _, request: "POST /<api> HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://<ip1>:443/<api>", host: "<ip>"
2022/04/24 23:10:20 [error] 912419#912419: *5 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: xxxxxxxx, server: _, request: "POST /<api> HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://<ip2>43/<api>", host: "<ip>"
2022/04/24 23:10:20 [error] 912419#912419: *5 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: xxxxxxxx, server: _, request: "POST /<api> HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://<ip3>:443/<api>", host: "<ip>"
```

Comment: please show us your full `nginx.conf`, you can dump it by executing command `nginx -T`

Comment: Try to add `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` into your location block

Answer (score 0):

Add client certificate and private key to verify nginx and each back-end server. Using `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` instruction:

```sh
location /public/api {
   proxy_pass https://public.server.com/api;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/client.pem;  
   proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/client.key  
}
```